Problem creating and executing simple cron job
I know that cron is supposed to be "rock solid" and reliable and everything. But I cannot seem to get one simple job setup correctly
What have I done?

I've created a bash script and made it executable for everyone chmod a+x scriptname.sh
I tested it by executing it manually. It checks if a certain process is running and restarts it if necessary. It works
I checked cron is running with ps -ef | grep cron. It's showing me /usr/sbin/cron -f for root
I ran crontab -e and added the script like this

*/5 * * * * /full/path/to/script.sh

When saving, crontab told me that is has been installing new crontab
Now, when I kill the process and wait for much more than 5 minutes ... nothing happens. The process will not be restarted.
I must be doing something very wrong very stupidly.
EDIT: I checked journalctl and found the following regular entries every 5 minutes. Yet, the script either doesn't run ... or the process started from it doesn't persist when the cron session ends??
Jun 26 09:40:01 raspberrypi CRON[2135]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user XXXXXX(uid=1000) by (uid=0)
Jun 26 09:40:01 raspberrypi CRON[2135]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user XXXXXX
Jun 26 09:45:01 raspberrypi CRON[2345]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user XXXXXX(uid=1000) by (uid=0)
Jun 26 09:45:01 raspberrypi CRON[2345]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user XXXXXX

This is the script being run:
#!/bin/bash
ps --no-headers -C node || sudo nohup node index.js > output.log 2>error.log &


It all came down to relative paths
The script ran locally because I ran it in the correct path. But when run from somewhere else, it failed. So cron had no chance
Simple change:
#!/bin/bash
cd /full/path/to
ps --no-headers -C node || sudo nohup node ./index.js >./output.log 2>./error.log &

